# Spring-rabbitmq - start spring-boot server even in case of lack of connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using spring boot with RabbitMQ. Everything is working - processing messages works and after losing connection it automatically tries to reconnect.  However,

I have only one problem:
When Rabbit server is swtiched off (no possibility to establish connection) and I try to launch spring-boot server it can't start. I can't check now (no access to machine) what exact content of exception is, however it was about problem with instatiation of beans.   Can you help me ?

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig{
       private String queueName = "myQueue";
       private String echangeName = "myExchange";

      @Bean
        public FanoutExchange exchange(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin)   {
            FanoutExchange exch = new 
             FanoutExchange(echangeName);
            rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(exch);
            return exch;
        }

        @Bean
        public Queue queue(FanoutExchange exchange, RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin) {
        HashMap<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        args.put("x-message-ttl", 20);
        args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", "dlx_exchange_name");

            Queue queue = new Queue(queueName, true, false, false, args);
            rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
            rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange));
            return queue;
        }

 }
```

**Edit**
I must edit, because I was not aware of fact that is is important here. 
In my case the last argument  is not null, it is some Hashmap (it is important for me). I edited my code above.

Moreover, I don't understand your answer exactly. Could you be more precisely ?
In order make sure that I was sufficiently clear: I would like to take advantage of automatic reconnection (now it is working). Additionally, If **during starting spring boot server rabbit broker is shutdown** it should start and cyclically try to reconnect (at this moment application doesn't start).

**Edit2**

```
  @Configuration
    public class RabbitConfig{
           private String queueName = "myQueue";
           private String echangeName = "myExchange";

          @Bean
            public FanoutExchange exchange(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin)   {
                FanoutExchange exch = new 
                 FanoutExchange(echangeName);
                //rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(exch);
                return exch;
            }

            @Bean
            public Queue queue(FanoutExchange exchange, RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin) {
            HashMap<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            args.put("x-message-ttl", 20);
            args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", "dlx_exchange_name");

                Queue queue = new Queue(queueName, true, false, false, args);
                //rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
                //rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange));
                return queue;
            }
         // EDIT 3: now, we are made to create binding bean

        @Autowired
        Queue queue; // inject bean by name
        @Autowired
        Exchange exchange;

        @Bean
        public Binding binding() {
             return BindingBuilder.bind(queue.to(exchange);
        }    

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. You try to register Broker entities manually:

```
rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(exch);
...
rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange));
```

You should rely here on the built-in auto-declaration mechanism in the [Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#broker-configuration).

In other words: you're good to declare those beans (including `Binding`m BTW), but you have not to call `rabbitAdmin.declare` at all. At least not from the bean definition phase.

Comment: I edited my question and add more details why I use `declare`. Can you look again ?

Comment: Your `args` isn't related. You have just not to call `rabbitAdmin.declare..` from `@Bean` definition methods. You shouldn't call it at all in most cases. I don't know how to explain you yet, but there is no manual `rabbitAdmin.declare..` in the Doc I pointed to you. You can find some useful content in the samples BTW: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples. The code I show in my answer is wrong. Say "No!" to  `rabbitAdmin.declare..` in the `@Bean`s !

Comment: Ok, I edited again and tried to correct it. Can you look? In particular - should I remove declaring exchanges also ?

Comment: OK. Now it looks very close to what I mean. Right, you don't have to use those `declare...` methods at all. But at the same time you have to specify `Binding` `@Bean` to let the Framework to `declare` for you when the connection to the Broker is available. The Doc I pointed explains everything. Please, consider to start from there in the next time. We have plenty other work to do rather than do your own for you...

Comment: BTW, it is generally never a good idea to interact with an external sever during the building of a `@Bean` declaration. `rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);` and such, should __never__ be performed in a `@Bean`.

Comment: Now, the question is if removing `declare` will still create queue on non-existence ? @GaryRussell I can't see any other way. I base on http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: That's correct. That is one of the main AMQP feature - declare broker entities if they don't exist, otherwise ignore. Why don't read that Doc first of all?..

Comment: @ArtemBilan I read it, but there is much information at the same time. So queues will be created on non-existence. I edited my corrected code to add bean with bindings. Is it what do you mean now ?

Comment: There is a section like http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#automatic-declaration. That's not fair for us to write that Doc then duplicate it here for you because you are not going to read it. We have already spent plenty of time here chatting rather than you would read the docs and study samples. I suppose I answer to your question "Why it doesn't start?". Everything rest is already outside of this SO thread scope.

Comment: Ok, I edited and edited in order to make it possible to use this thread for other people.

Comment: Yes, I am going to accept your answer, I was expecting to clarify corectness of  binding bean. When I gain actual number of points I vote up here also, thanks

Comment: To be clear, @Bean declarations are setting up your static application environment. It is not wise to do anything except set bean properties in that phase of the application initialization.